# wp_enqueue_script stopped working

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm facing a strange problem. After I've moved to another server, my wp_enqueue_script calls don't do anything. I do have this function:

```
function moemax_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.1', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.min.js', array(), array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'moemax-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'moemax-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'moemax-skip-link-focus-fix', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    wp_enqueue_style( 'core-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/core.min.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}
```

The strange thing is, all my css files get included, but none of the js files are added to the site. I tried to change $handle, $ver or even $src but nothing is happening. I don't get any errors in console.

Comment: Your `main-js` has two array() declaration - which is wrong. It'd be helpful using the developer tool's "Console" while working with javascripts.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Changed that, but still no change. Javascript isn't showing up. And as I told you, my console don't show any errors.

Comment: Put all the `wp_enqueue_style()` on the top, and `wp_enqueue_script()` below them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem would be, but I'd start out by checking to see if they are actually getting enqueued.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is

That would at least let you know if you have a declaration problem of if there is something wrong when enqueued scripts are being drawn. (like a plugin conflict or some such)

Answer (score 0):

you need to register and enqueue style / script..

```
wp_register_style('mystyle', plugins_url('/css/mystyle.css', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle' );

wp_register_script('myscript', plugins_url('/js/myscript.js', __FILE__));
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript' );
```

Comment: No, it is not neessary. You don't have to, you can simply just enqueue. :-)